# Pandas - using group by and including value counts which are larger than n

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table which includes `salary` and `company_location`.

I was trying to calculate the mean salary of a country, its works:

```
wage = df.groupby('company_location').mean()['salary']
```

However, I have many with `company_location` which have less than 5 entries, I would like to exclude them from the report.

I know how to calculate countries with the top 5 entries:

```
Top_5 = df['company_location'].value_counts().head(5)
```

I am just having a problem connecting those to variables into one and making a graph out of it...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove rows whose value occurrence is below a threshold:

```
df = df[df.groupby('company_location')['company_location'].transform('size') > 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to only apply the groupby and aggregation to those with more than 5 records:

```
mask = (df['company_location'].map(df['company_location'].value_counts()) > 5)

wage = df[mask].groupby('company_location')['salary'].mean()
```